# Data structures and format in matlab vs python?

Tags: python, matlab, data-structures

I have come to the conclusion that I simply do not understand python as well as I thought.

after a great many tries in python, I tried writing the same thing in Matlab and it just worked.
What my conclusion is, is that the way structures work is just a lot different from what I expect and I cannot see what that difference is.
For example in python, it could have a structure that looks like [[1], [2], [3]] and in Matlab, it would be [1,2,3]. running a loop over i in python would yield only [1] and the same in Matlab would be the sequence.
I remedied this by using np.hstack to get [1,2,3], so I fixed that issue, but I suspect that the rest of my issue right now is also structure-based. in the Matlab code, I get a coupling and the numbers converge. However, in my python code, all of them diverge.

Is there a great resource on how data structures work in python, that isn't the python doc, maybe something that compares Matlab and Python structures? or does anyone have an idea of how I should restructure my Python code?

EDIT: the code is an attempt at euler integration of coupled oscillators, where each oscillator couples to all of its neigbours

it takes in a frequency, w, as this is a solution for a coupling constant of K = 0
a loop runs from each oscillator i, over each neighbour j.

dTheta[i] is the frequency of the current oscillator in the loop.
k/N indicates the coupling strength based on the number of neighbours and theta[j,c] and theta[i,c] is respectively the previous angles for neighbour and current oscillator

a new angle is then assigned based on the integration step of the frequency

in Matlab, I wrote the following

```
%% Initialize items
k = 1;                                                                      %coupling factor
N = 20 ;                                                                    %Number of oscillators
tend = 10;
dt= tend/200;
t = 0:dt:tend;
theta=zeros(N,length(t));
theta(:,1)=abs(2*pi*rand(N,1));
dTheta=zeros(N,1);
w = .1.*ones(N,1);                                                          %Set the frequency of the oscillators
y = zeros(size(theta));

%% Calculations
for c=2:length(t)
    dTheta=w;
    for i=1:N
        for j=1:N
            dTheta(i)=dTheta(i)+((k/N)*sin(theta(j,c-1)-theta(i,c-1)));     %Genereate delta theta.
        end
    end
    theta(:,c)=theta(:,c-1)+(dTheta*dt);                                    %Euler forward step
    c/length(t);
end

for c=1:length(t)
    y(:,c)=sin((5*t(c))+theta(:,c));                                        %Generate the y.
end
```

in python I have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 1
N = 10
tend = 20
dt = tend*4
t = np.linspace(0,tend,dt)
theta = np.zeros((N,len(t)))
theta[:,0] = 2*np.pi*abs(np.random.randint(0, high=N ,size=(N)))/10
dTheta = np.hstack(np.zeros((N,1)))
w = np.hstack(20*np.ones((N,1)))
y = np.zeros(theta.shape)

for c in range(1,len(t)):
    dTheta=w
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            dTheta[i] = dTheta[i] + ((k/N)*np.sin(theta[j,c-1] - theta[i,c-1]))
    theta[:,c] = theta[:,c-1] + (dTheta*dt)
    c/len(t)

for c in range(len(t)):
   y[:,c] = np.sin((5*t[c]) + theta[:,c])

plt.figure()
for c in range(N):
    plt.plot(t,y[c,:])

plt.figure()
for c in range(N):
    plt.plot(t,theta[c,:])
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html ?

Comment: Your first example has created a 2D array: `[[1], [2], [3]]`. I have a hard time believing that such structures don't also exist in Matlab and I'm not sure they would be surprising. How you _got to that_ is probably the surprising part and something we might be able to help with

Comment: You might find it useful to build some debugging in, for example print the delta each loop and compare, maybe even print the whole of theta and just do a  visual check.

Comment: @roganjosh good point, matlab certainly does have 2d arrays, in fact all variables in matlab are n-dimensional arrays by default if I recall directly. The fact that the OP has ended up with a 2D array in numpy does suggest something unwanted is going on.

Comment: It would help to know what the code is meant to do. Bumpy.zeros((4,10))  creates an empty 2d array with 4 rows and 10 columns. Theta[:,1] should select the second element of each row.

Comment: @roganjosh That is an excellent link, it already helped a bit. Thank you :)
I'm used to using zeros() in Matlab and found numpy's version of it, as numpy.zeros(). using np.zeros(N,1) gives the float structure `[[0], [0], [0]]` or np.zeros(1,N) yields `[[0, 0, 0]]`, but both seems to be nested? using np.hstack I get `[0, 0, 0]` which is what I think of as a matrix in this context. In Matlab, I could produce nested structures, but usually, that would be part of a "struct" instead or a cell with arrays. in my experience with matlab, nested arrays were something I deliberately had to construct

Comment: @BNewmark I will edit in a short description of the code in the main segment.
But I think I made an assumption that it would work as in Matlab, for example, for Theta[j,i], Theta[0,0] would call the zeroth index for j and i column/row and that Theta[:,0] call all values in j for zeroth index of i. trying the same now, also does the same
'y = np.random.randint(0,10,(N,N))' gives an array 'y[0,0]' yields the zeroth index of i and j 'y[:,0]' yields all entries in the column

Comment: We're getting closer :) Some of this may be due to the different indexing between the two languages (python using zero-based indexing). `np.zeros(N)` gives you the array

Comment: Hm ok that comment is helpful but I meant more of a "which value is written to which index of which array" kind of description. The line in the python part assigning 20*array(N,1) to w seems a bit fishy to me. That would be an array of  dim 400x1?